# export model from blender to three.js is show up inverted

Tags: three.js

I had create a dice in blender and then export it to three.js but when I load it in the scene then it showing up inverted.
http://www.sggame.bugs3.com/dice.html

Comment: Your normals are inverted.

Comment: how to change them in blender?

Comment: sorry don't know blender.

Comment: i done it in blender by flip the normals inside and recalculate the normals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it in blender software by flip the normals inside of the object and recalculate the normals. then agiain export it to three.js